# Multiple-Word Model in a Cucumber / Pickle statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, pickle

I can't find any examples of how to use models that contain multiple words in a Pickle / Cucumber statement. Here is the statement:

Given a visitor_activity_type exists with name:"ContactForm"

I've tried with spaces, no spaces, underscores, and camel casing.  But nothing seems to work. Of course, maybe I'm doing something else wrong. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple word work just fine, actually (with spaces). Most likely you're missing the factory for the model class you want to use.